# Fixed content on mobile devices, a good workaround?

Tags: css, grid, popup, media-queries, user-experience

I'm currently developing a website with CSS Grid, and I have been trying to tweak it as nice as possible in regards to responsive design. It looks great on all devices from `width: 320px` and up, however, my only problem right now is that I have a few buttons on my website that creates a modal/pop-up window, i.e. a fixed overlay. On a bit large screens it looks great, and also for `width: 320px`, but if the screen height gets too small, I can't do much more right now to remove stuff from the pop-up window through media queries without making it useless. And it isn't scrollable as you probably know, so I'm kind of at a dead end right now.

So, is there some kind of cool solution to pop-up windows on smaller screens, or is the only way to not create pop-up windows ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just make the pop-up scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

First if all: try not to put too much content and functionality in your modal windows. Especially on mobile devices they are often perceived negatively by your users. Instead, try to solve simple tasks on the page (possibly progressive) or complex tasks on a separate page. If you have more content for your modal than fits on a small screen, your task might be too big for a modal window.

With regards to the implementation: there is different methods for implementing modal windows/pop-ups that should also provide scrolling. Can you tell us how you implemented it, and which alternatives you've tried?